# Is gcc's optimizer doing something weird here?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I have a program that triggers `-Wmaybe-uninitialized` while using any kind of optimizations (`-O1`, `-O2`, `-O3`) the following is the smallest code I could make that reproduces this behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

struct result {
    int res;
};

struct graph {
    int vertices[5];
};

// In reality this is a backtracking search.
void computational_search (struct graph *g, struct result *out) {
    out->res = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        out->res += g->vertices[i];
    }
}

// In reality queries a database of geometrical graphs.
void next_graph (struct graph *g)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        g->vertices[i] += rand();
    }
}

enum format_t {
    FMT = 1,
    FMT_1 = 2
};

int main()
{
    int val = rand()%10;
    int num_graphs = 5;

    struct graph g;
    struct result res;

    uint64_t *count;
    if (val & FMT) {
        count = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t)*num_graphs);
    }

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<num_graphs; i++) {
        next_graph (&g);
        computational_search (&g, &res);
        if (val & FMT) {
            count[i] = res.res; /* ERROR HERE */
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm aware there is an execution path where `count` is uninitialized, but it's not being used there. Can the optimizer be doing something that may use `count` uninitialized?.

Compilig with `gcc -Wall -O1 test.c` outputs this on gcc 5.4.0:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:43:15: warning: ‘count’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     uint64_t *count;
               ^
```

The same happens for `-O2` and `-O3`, but not for `-O0`.

Comment: Can you add the compiler output?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the error is and where.

Comment: Not reproducible on `gcc 5.4.0`

Comment: Just because you can see that `arr` must be initialized before use doesn't mean that the compiler can prove it. Proving it in the general case is undecidable.

Comment: *"Is gcc's optimizer doing something weird here?"* - Usually, but with good reason.

Comment: So you have a variable which is not initialized and not used (in your specific use-case). Seems like a perfectly good reason for a warning? This is not how you write stable code. There's no apparent reason to use malloc in the first place. Always stack allocate and initialize the variable, problem solved. Weird code gets weird problems.

Comment: *why* do you perform these loop-invariant tests inside a loop? Do you expect the compiler to hoist them out of the loop?

Comment: It's full of 'if (val & FMT)' Would it not be easier to put 'if (!(val & FMT)) return 0;' at the top?

Comment: Which version of the compiler `gcc -v`?

Comment: The optimiser does static analysis of the execution path. The one you are using probably doesn't bother to figure out that the expression will have the same value in each of those cases.

Comment: `(val & 1) && (val & 2)` is turned into `(val & 3) == 3`, but then gcc doesn't see any more that it implies `(val & 1) != 0`. At -O3 it unrolls the loop and simplifies enough not to warn.

Comment: Why was my example code edited?, I had to add some random values exactly to force the optimizer (even for -O3) to not unroll the loop, with this version -O3 will unroll the loop and not warn. Also, main was changed for foo, now it does not compile as easily as before. Am I allowed to revert the example to what it was before?

Comment: I just added how I'm compiling and the output I get. This is only an easy to compile version of my actual code, the real code I'm using has a much more complex loop that isn't unrolled even with `-O3`. The original example I posted (before it was edited) had this behavior too.

Comment: Yes — it is your question and if crucial elements have been changed, then you're fully entitled to revert the changes. However, you should take that as a hint to document that the lines are crucial. And you should avoid writing code that runs the risk of confusing the compiler. It doesn't matter whether the compiler is right or wrong. If it can't work it out, it will go wrong, and you should do your utmost to modify the code to avoid the risk of confusing the compiler. (It'll also confuse users of the code, and future maintainers of the code, and the warnings might come and go with upgrades.)

Comment: Also, the reason I'm not using the stack here is the array may be very big in my actual code, and that's also why I'm using a flag to enable allocation only when the caller of the function actually needs it.

Comment: Okay, so I think in my attempt to make a simpler version of my code that could be compiled easily I caused some confusion. I changed the example code to better resemble my usecase. As you can see, the condition is always the same `val & FMT`. The reasoning behind `format_t` is that it enables storing some statistics about the execution, but these may be quite expensive memory wise, so they won't be computed unless the user actually needs them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me say it a bit bluntly: `-Wmaybe-uninitialized` sucks. What GCC actually tries to do is first perform a lot of optimizing transformations and then check that every use of a variable is preceded by an initialization (hoping that the optimizer is smart enough to get all impossible paths eliminated). IIRC it also has a couple of simple heuristics. With such an approach you should expect false positives.

For example at `-O3` the compiler should unswitch the loop in `main` and transform it into something like this:

```
if (val & FMT) {
    for (i=0; i<num_graphs; i++) {
        next_graph (&g);
        computational_search (&g, &res);
        count[i] = res.res;
    }
} else {
    for (i=0; i<num_graphs; i++) {
        next_graph (&g);
        computational_search (&g, &res);
    }
}
```

Then it should notice that we already have a `val & FMT` check and merge the corresponding branches:

```
if (val & FMT) {
    count = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t)*num_graphs);
    for (i=0; i<num_graphs; i++) {
        next_graph (&g);
        computational_search (&g, &res);
        count[i] = res.res;
    }
} else {
    for (i=0; i<num_graphs; i++) {
        next_graph (&g);
        computational_search (&g, &res);
    }
}
```

The path involving an uninitialized use is gone. Now, back to the reality: unswitching does not happen (for some reason). If you add `-fno-inline` (note: it's just a test, I'm not proposing it as a solution), it does happen and everything works as I described earlier (no warning). IMHO, this warning is very brittle and unpredictable.

> Can the optimizer be doing something that may use count
>   uninitialized?.

No, unless it has a bug.

Comment: Thanks! this is a nice explanation of what the compiler should be doing. What I still find confusing is why `-Wmaybe-uninitialized` is implied by `-Wall` and `-Wuninitialized` isn't, it seems like the first one is more prone to trigger on false positives than the second one.

Comment: It might be a documentation bug. `-Wall` implies `-Wuninitialized`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler appears correct.  It is not noticing that you have the same if statement for both use cases, so the latter is treated separately from the former it is seen as a declare a pointer with no memory behind it then use it as if it has memory behind it.

```
uint64_t *count;
...
        if (val & FMT) {
            count[i] = res.res; /* ERROR HERE */
        }
```

gcc is not as smart as you think it is or should be.

EDIT

for many years gcc has not complained about this

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int x )
{
    switch(x&3)
    {
        case 0: return(x);
        case 1: return(x<<1);
        case 2: return(x>>1);
        case 3: return(x+1);
    }
    return(3);
}
```

But used to complain if you didnt have a return after the switch.  Insisted on you putting in dead code that cannot be reached, then complained when you did.  No win situation.

Just tried with 5.4.0 against x86 and it doesnt complain either way.  Tried with 7.2.0 against arm and it doesnt complain either way.

Happy to see they removed at least one issue, but would like to see both.

There are other optimization bugs that I have found and expect to find more in the future.  You are welcome to try to file yours as a bug and see what they say.

Comment: So, do you think this should be reported as a bug?, other cases I've tried do detect the condition is the same and don't complain about it.

Comment: You can try, I dont expect you will get very far but someone will at least look at your ticket and close it or not...